# Как сделать картинку посредине

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sublime-text-3, layout

Пишу на `css` на `bootstrap` и не понимаю как разместить картинку по центру

[image]

Помогите пожалуйста кто знает (прошу код)
Код на `github` чтобы его можно было *"потрогать"*
(залил потому что нужны исходники картинок для воспроизведения проблеммы)
https://github.com/Nicitaa/html-css-js/blob/main/Questions/svgLayout.zip
[image: Как скачать]

Comment: повесь на картинки свойства `display: block` и `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: @rusgeli благодарю - помогло - можешь в ответы написать я одобрю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повесь на картинки свойства `display: block` и `margin: 0 auto`

Ответ дан:[@rusgeli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/508294/rusgeli)